# Accessing DB2 with SQL Developer via ODBC (not JDBC)

Tags: jdbc, db2, odbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

Due to company constraints, I cannot read my DB2 tables using the Oracle SQL Developer.

I could do it via JDBC, but I don’t have enough information to configure the connection (e.g. the port is missing).

I found in my local Windows ODBC list a system DNS ( IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER – DEFAULT_DB2) that I can use with Microsoft Access.

I mean, tables are accessible via MS Access through an ODBC DNS.

I’d like to do the same with SQL Developer too.  Is it possible?
***May I use my local ODBC system DNS in SQL Developer or something like this?***

I see that ODBC connections are possible with SQL Server, MySql, Sybase and other databases but I cannot find anything about DB2.
Additionally, if it helps, I can see my DB2 server via QMF (already registered by the company software distribution) but I don’t think this is useful for me.

Comment: The current SQL Developer version requires Java 8 - the JDBC/ODBC bridge was removed in in Java 8, so there is no way you can use SQL Developer with an ODBC connection

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name, I installed a third party JDBC driver db2jcc.jar to access DB2 via JDBC.
Does exist something similar to do it via ODBC using the same DNS (already used by MS Access successfully) defined in my local machine?